# using union command on three tables (mysql)

Tags: mysql, union

I have the following:

```
tblOwner: owner_num,lname,fname (PK owner_num)
tblMarina_slip: owner_num, slip_id (PK slip_id, FK owner_num)
tblService_Requests: service_id, slip_id, description (PK service_id, FK slip_id)
```

I am new to MySql and need to use a Union command to get an output of

```
tblOwner.Owner_num, tblOwner.Lname, tblOwner.Fname, tblServiceRequests.service_id, tblServiceRequests.Description
```

**I have no idea how to use a "union" command to get the required dataset**, when the only connection between these three tables the foreign keys in tblMarina_slip and tblService_Requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a union comand:

```
select  tow.Owner_num, tow.Lname, tow.Fname, ts.service_id, ts.Description
  from  tblOwner tow, tblServiceRequests ts, tblMarina_slip tm
 where  tow.owner_num = tm.owner_num
   and  tm.slip_id    = ts.slip_id
```

Comment: thank you very much the assignment directions really had me second guessing all that. appreciate the clarification on this. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need a join not a union :

```
SELECT t.owner_num,t.Lname,t.Fname,s.service_id,s.description
FROM tblOwner t 
INNER JOIN tblMarina_slip p on(t.owner_num = p.owner_num)
INNER JOIN tblService_Requests s on(p.slip_id = s.slip_id)
```

A union is used to combine two or more outputs together (only in case they are the same with the column numbers and column types)

When you want to display more then one table info in the same row, you should use JOIN like in my answer.

**EDIT:**

If you are required to use union, you can trick the data like this:

```
SELECT max(owner_num),max(Lname),max(Fname),slip_id,max(description)
FROM
    (SELECT owner_num,max(Lname) as Lname,max(Fname) as Fname, max(slip_id) as slip_id,'' as description
    FROM(
        SELECT owner_num,Lname,Fname,0 as slip_id from tblOwner
        UNION
        SELECT owner_num,'' as Lname,'' as Fname,slip_id from tblMarina_slip)
    GROUP BY owner_num
    UNION
    SELECT 0 as owner_num, '' as Lname, '' as Fname,slip_id,description FROM tblService_Requests)
GROUP BY slip_id
```

Comment: the assigment directions state "use the union command to complete a results table satisfying this request.  been scratching my head all night, because unions need same number of columns and types.

Comment: Yossi im just going to use the join, and ask my instructor to clarify this one. thanks I believe the "join" gets the information I need, even though the assignment says "use the union command".  appreciate it.

Comment: @NateE. I provided you a UNION solution.. it is possible and should work good. Anyways, I'll appreciate if you accept my answer if it helped you

Answer (score -1):

```
select col1,col2,col3 from <tablename> where <conditions> 
union
    select col1,col2,col3 from <tablename> where <conditions> 
union
    select col1,col2,col3 from <tablename> where <conditions>
```

Note : `col1`, `col2`, `col3` from each table must be identical.

Comment: the 3 tables dont have the same number of columns, thats why i dont understand how I can use a union command (per the assignment directions) to join them to get the required dataset. the only connection i can see if the foreign key, but i cant figure out how to use a union on it.